# JavaFX application does not start (MacOS using JDK11)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, javafx

I am trying to run a JavaFX application on Eclipse. The code is based on the directions from https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle under "JavaFX and Eclipse" --> "Modular from IDE". However, when I try to run the application, no window appears.

I am using a MacBook Pro 2018, and the only thing that appears is an image with a cup of coffee on the Dock that is named "java". I can't quit from it. The only for it to quit and stop is to forcibly terminate the program from Eclipse.

```
package org.openjfx;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Gradle");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

```
module hellofx {

    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires transitive javafx.base;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;

    opens org.openjfx to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.openjfx;

}
```

```
package org.openjfx;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class FXMLController {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    public void initialize() {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
        label.setText("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + "\nRunning on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
    }    
}
```

"scene.fxml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>


<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.openjfx.FXMLController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="label" text="Label" />
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

"style.css"

```
.button {
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Image of console when running. There are no exceptions thrown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osDhB.png)

[Project Folder Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jw1i.png)

Comment: Show your work.

Comment: Please post the fxml file. Also check for any exceptions and post them.

Comment: Added. There does not appear to be exceptions.

Comment: This is precisely the same issue I am having. JavaFX is ridiculous.